# How to show flutter native splash screen when authentication loading?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I would like to check the authentication login state as below

1. authentication loading => show splash screen
2. authenticated=> home screen
3. unauthenticated=>sign in screen

Currently, I am using GetX state management
I wish, on authentication loading state then show flutter_native_splash_screen rather than my customize splash screen due to rendering, it shows a black screen before my customized splash finished render.

**Here is my code**

```
void main() async {
  var widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  internalInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
  FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
}

void internalInitialized() {
  Get.lazyPut(() => AuthController(Get.put(AuthService())));
}


class MyApp extends GetWidget<AuthController> {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Obx(() {
        if (controller.state is Authenticated) {
          return HomeScreen((controller.state as Authenticated).user!);
        } else if (controller.state is UnAuthenticated) {
          return SignInScreen();
        } else {
          return const SplashScreen();
        }
      }),
      theme: lightTheme(),
      darkTheme: darkTheme(),
      getPages: AppPages.list,
    );
  }
}
```

**Splash Screen**

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig.init(context);
    return Container(
        color: AppTheme.primaryColor,
        width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
        height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: getHeight(150),
              height: getHeight(150),
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
            ),
            const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white)
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

The customize splash screen just show Logo and processing bar.
**Auth Controller**

```
class AuthController extends ConnectivityController {
  final AuthService authService;
  final authStateStream = const AuthenticationState().obs;

  AuthController(this.authService);

  AuthenticationState get state => authStateStream.value;

 
  @override
  void onInit() {
    getAuthenticatedUser();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<void> signIn(String username, String password) async {
    authStateStream.value = AuthenticationLoading();
    final customer = await authService.sign(username, password);
    if (customer == null) {
      authStateStream.value = UnAuthenticated();
    } else {
      authStateStream.value = Authenticated(customer: customer);
    }
  }

  void signOut() async {
    await authService.signOut("");
    authStateStream.value = UnAuthenticated();
  }

  void getAuthenticatedUser() async {
    authStateStream.value = AuthenticationLoading();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    final customer = await authService.reSignIn();
    if (customer == null) {
      authStateStream.value = UnAuthenticated();
    } else {
      authStateStream.value = Authenticated(customer: customer);
    }
  }
}
```

Please guide me, on how can I solve this issue.
Thank you!

Comment: please provide controller and splashscreen code.

Comment: Hi @Mahi,
I done updated, please you check it

Comment: controller class?

Comment: @Mahi, yes I just update my question

Answer (score 0):

The splash screen is meant to be displayed whilst the bundled Flutter engine initialises.
Once that is done and your app is in control, you can manually create a page that looks like the splash screen. So the child of the material app can be a splash screen look alike. Maybe you could even make it identical to your splash screen asset.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

first `initialize` your state and use `conditional` operator if it is authenticated than go to `splashScreen`  else `authenticate` .

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();   
    var _isAuth = user != null && user.isVerified;
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => _isAuth ? SplashScreen() : Authenticate()),
    );
  }
```